# How do I get my background image to load before Javascript program runs?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get my HTML background Image to load before my JavaScript program loads. Currently the JavaScript program loads and then after the program is done the Background image will show. I am rather new to coding so any help would be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
</head>

<body background="9-RPS-example.png">

<script type="text/javascript ">
    const computerchoice = ["r ", "p ", "s "];

    let wins = 0;
    let losses = 0;
    let ties = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        computerguess = computerchoice[Math.floor(Math.random() * computerchoice.length)];

        console.log(computerguess);

        alert("Welcome to RPS!!! You Know what Beats what. Press Ok to play ");
        var userguess = prompt("Choose r, p , or s. Sorry no Spocks allowed ");
        console.log(userguess);
        userguess = userguess.toLowerCase();
        // if (userguess === "r " || userguess === "p " || userguess === "s ") {
        // alert("The Computer Guessed " + computerguess + " You Guessed " + userguess)
        if ((userguess === "r " && computerguess === "s ") ||
            (userguess === "p " && computerguess === "r ") ||
            (userguess === "s " && computerguess === "p ")) {
            wins++;
            alert("The Computer Guessed " + computerguess + " You Guessed " + userguess + " 
You Won " + wins + " Time(s) ")
        } else if ((userguess === "r " && computerguess === "p ") ||
            (userguess === "p " && computerguess === "s ") ||
            (userguess === "s " && computerguess === "r ")) {
            losses++;
            alert("The Computer Guessed " + computerguess + " You Guessed " + userguess + " 
You lost " + losses + " Time(s) ")
        } else if (userguess === computerguess) {
            ties++;
            alert("The Computer Guessed " + computerguess + " You Guessed " + userguess + "  
You Tied " + ties + " Time(s) ")
        } else
            alert("You did not guess r, p or s...Dummy ")
    }
</script>

</body>

</html>˚
```

Answer (score 0):

The background image should be set using the CSS [background-image](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images_background.asp) property. Try replacing your `background` tag with `style="background-image: url('9-RPS-example.png')"`

```
<body style="background-image: url('9-RPS-example.png')">
```

Comment: I couldn't seem to get this to work. Still wouldn't load the image.

Comment: I apologize, I didn't look at your code close enough. The background image can't be set that way. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I have added <body style="background-image: url('9-RPS-example.png')"> and window.addEventListener('load', function() { javascript here }); with no luck. Program loads before background.